# Laravel 10, Tailwind CSS class not working properly

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I install tailwindcss into my **Laravel** prioject. Some classes are not working properly. i used "text-red-500" inside a

tag to display the text color red and it working, but if i use "text-red-200" it won't working.

inside the **tailwind.config.js** content section:

```
content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
],
```

I tried in **app.css**

`@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`

and

`@import "tailwindcss/base"; @import "tailwindcss/components"; @import "tailwindcss/utilities";`

both method separately but still not working

how can i fix this problem?

I have the project folder inside **resources/view/admin**

I tried "**text-red-500**" inside a

tag to display the text color red and it working, but if i use "**text-red-200**" it won't working.

I want to fix the issue.

Comment: I used npm run dev but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project is inside a folder, resources/view/admin, that is not safelisted in your Tailwind config, so any styles written there will be removed. Solution? Add the path for your project to your Tailwind config.